# Was Salesforce able to match by external Id fields in import wizard (not unique)

Tags: data-import-wizard

Our support team raised a ticket for us that they no longer see an external id field in the match by section in the import wizard:

[image]

Our customer claimed they see the external field in the match by section till last Friday.

I checked that external field. It has external Id checked by unique unchecked.

I tested that if I check the unique checkbox it will instantly work. But our business is not sure about whether we should do that.

I am a little bit confused because due to this article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002783&type=1 . The field should be unique in order to be shown in the match by section. I am lost in why our customer was able to see it.

My guess is it could be:

1. Salesforce was somehow forced the external Id to be unique but recently changed it.
2. External Id (not unique) was able to be used in data import wizard before.

But I didn't find any related document of that. I checked the version of the org and it is still Spring 17 so shouldn't be a big change last week. So I am still very confused.

Any suggestions?

Comment: might be an user error.. I don't think Import (specifically update / upsert) would have ever supported non unique external ids..

Answer (score 1):

I just got the response back from Salesforce. It seems to be an known issue: 
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gOnQAI&title=non-unique-external-id-fields-are-incorrectly-available-for-selection-as-matching-criteria-in-the-data-import-wizard

Comment: I've read it as, we should never have been able to use a non-unique external Id in the import wizard.